# DFS to find all possible path is very slow

Tags: python, depth-first-search

I wrote DFS-like algorithm to find all possible paths starting from zero level.
With 2,000 nodes and 5,000 edges, below code execution is extremely slow.
Any suggestion for this algorithm?

```py
    all_path = []

    def printAllPathsUntil(s, path):
        path.append(s)
        if s not in adj or len(adj[s]) <= 0:
            all_path.append(path[:]) # EDIT2
        else:
            for i in adj[s]:
                printAllPathsUntil(i, path)
        path.pop()

    for point in points_in_start:
        path = []
        printAllPathsUntil(point, path)
```

And the `adj` holds edges; start position as key and destination list as value.

```py
    points_in_start = [0, 3, 7]
    adj = {0: [1, 8],
           1: [2, 5],
           2: [],
           3: [2, 4],
           4: [],
           5: [6],
           6: [],
           7: [6],
           8: [2]
           }
```

#### EDIT1

- This is a DAG. No cycles.

[image]

Comment: Are there loops in your graph? Also, unless you mark nodes as visited, you'll do the same work over and over again if you find a new path to the same node; that means that the amount of work will grow a lot more than necessary. The number of nodes and the number of edges is one thing, but the graph layout without any tracking will make it hard to do DFS (or BFS) efficiently.

Comment: Unrelated to being slow, but it seems you are adding references to _the same_ `path` over and over again. You probably want `all_path.append(path[::])`

Comment: Also, could you add the full `adj` for that small example?

Comment: Sample `adj` and `points_in_start` added. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your algorithm is that it will do a lot of repeated work. This is not the case in your example, as the only time when a node is reached by two other nodes, it is a leaf node, like `C`, but imaging an edge from `D` to `B`: That would mean that the entire sub-graph starting at `B` is visited again! For a graph with 2000 nodes, this will result in a significant slow-down.

To counter this, you can use memoization, but this means that you have to restructure your algorithm to instead of adding to the existing `path` and then adding that `path` to `all_paths`, it has to `return` the (partial) paths starting at the current node and combine those to the full paths with the parent node. You can then use `functools.lru_cache` to re-use all those partial results when you visit `B` again coming from another node.

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(None)
def getAllPathsUntil(s):
    if s not in adj or not adj[s]:
        return [ [s] ]
    else:
        return [ [s, *p] for a in adj[s]
                         for p in getAllPathsUntil(a)]

all_paths = []
for point in points_in_start:
    all_paths.extend(getAllPathsUntil(point))
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out already in the comments and other answers, remembering downstream paths of previously visited nodes is an area of optimization.

Here's my attempt at implementing that.

Here, `downstream_paths` is a dictionary where we remember, for each visited non-leaf node, the downstream paths from that node.

I have mentioned `%%timeit` results towards the end for a small test case containing a small case of "revisited non-leafs". Since my test case had only one case of a non-leaf node being re-visited, the improvement was only modest. Perhaps in your large-scale dataset, there will be a wider gap in the performance.

**Input data:**

```
points_in_start = [0, 3, 7]
adj = {0: [1, 8],
       1: [2, 5],
       2: [],
       3: [2, 4],
       4: [],
       5: [6],
       6: [],
       7: [6],
       8: [2],     # Non-leaf node "2" is a child of both "8" and "3"
       
       2:[10],
       
       10:[11,18],
       11:[12,15],
       12:[],
       15:[16],
       16:[],
       18:[12]
      }
```

**The modified code:**

```
%%timeit

downstream_paths = {}                                 # Maps each node to its
                                                      # list of downstream paths
                                                      # starting with that node.

def getPathsToLeafsFrom(s):      # Returns list of downstream paths starting from s
                                 # and ending in some leaf node.
    children = adj.get(s, [])
    if not children:                                  # s is a Leaf
        paths_from_s = [[s]]
    else:                                             # s is a Non-leaf
        ds_paths = downstream_paths.get(s, [])        # Check if s was previously visited
        if ds_paths:                                  # If s was previously visited.
            paths_from_s = ds_paths
        else:                                         # s was not visited earlier.
            paths_from_s = []                         # Initialize
            for child in children:
                paths_from_child = getPathsToLeafsFrom(child)   # Recurse for each child
                for p in paths_from_child:
                    paths_from_s.append([s] + p)
            downstream_paths[s] = paths_from_s       # Cache this, to use when s is re-visited
    return paths_from_s

path = []
for point in points_in_start:
    path.extend(getPathsToLeafsFrom(point))
```

**Output:**

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint (all_path)

[[0, 1, 2, 10, 11, 12],
 [0, 1, 2, 10, 11, 15, 16],
 [0, 1, 2, 10, 18, 12],
 [0, 1, 5, 6],
 [0, 8, 2, 10, 11, 12],
 [0, 8, 2, 10, 11, 15, 16],
 [0, 8, 2, 10, 18, 12],
 [3, 2, 10, 11, 12],
 [3, 2, 10, 11, 15, 16],
 [3, 2, 10, 18, 12],
 [3, 4],
 [7, 6]]
```

**Timing results: Original posted code:**

> 10000 loops, best of 3: 63 µs per loop

**Timing results: Optimized code:**

> 10000 loops, best of 3: 43.2 µs per loop

Comment: Thanks. but I cannot tell this is good approach because my pc lagged with this code. :(

Comment: @Dorr - Oh, I'm sorry. Lagged, with what size of data? Did it complete the run ? (Reason for asking is -- any possibility of cycles in your graph)